# Lennard-Jones potential and force in metals

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, condensed-matter, potential

First of all, let me say that this question is for a High School project, so a classical approach in 1D is enough.

I guess that the first question is, can a Lennard-Jones potential be used to (roughly) study distance between atoms in a metal?

Second, how can I calculate the force between to atoms in a metal using Lennard-Jones potential?

Comment: If your question is "what is a Lennard-Jones potential", you could start here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lennard-Jones_potential

Comment: Sorry if my question is not clear. What I would like to know is how I can calculate the force between two atoms in a metal using Lennard-Jones potential. I will edit my question.

Comment: The Lennard-Jones potential is not applicable to chemical bonds. It is an intermolecular potential.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Could you recommend another way of approaching this? Is there a simple potential that I can use to simulate interactions between atoms in a metal?

Comment: It is still unclear to me why you want to calculate the force between two atoms in a 1D approximation. What is the connection of such an exercise to metals? I am not sure if 1D  even exist, knowing that localisation in 1D happens if any perturbation is present.

Answer (score 2):

The point my2cts was making is the Lennard-Jones applies to covalently bonded neutral atoms or molecules. As the [Wikipedia article](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lennard-Jones_potential) he linked says, if they get too close, orbitals begin to overlap causing repulsion. Farther away there is a van der Waals attraction.

[Metallic bonds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metallic_bonding) are different. Conduction electrons detach from atoms and spread out through the metal. This leaves positively charged metal atoms that repel each other, but are attracted to the sea of electrons.

I Googled a bit, but did not find anything specifically about thermal expansion of metals. Most source assume a potential much like that pictured in Wikipedia. They expand in a Taylor series around the minimum, and show the cubic term leads to a linear thermal expansion coefficient. If you have a copy of Kittel, that might be the best reference. If not see [this](http://cryocourse2011.grenoble.cnrs.fr/IMG/file/Lectures/Amara-ThermalExpansion2011.pdf) or [this](http://www.physics.utah.edu/%7Elebohec/P5510/Notes/StevenSimonOxfordNotes2012.pdf).

The problems are that it gives no specific values that allow you to calculate the coefficient, and I don't know how applicable it is to metals.

My guess is that you will be OK with this type of model. Any potential that holds atoms together will have the general features of this potential.

- It will be high if two atoms approach each other closely.
- It will be $0$ (by convention) at infinite separation.
- It will have a minimum < $0$ in between.

Any such potential can be expanded in a Taylor series around the minimum. The cubic term will lead to a linear coefficient of expansion.

Note the sign of the cubic term must be + to get a + coefficient. Most substances do, but a few have odd things going on that make them contract as temperature rises. For example rubber bands have long molecules with a sawtooth shape. As the temperature rises, increased vibrations for some reason make the teeth get sharper on average. Water within a few degrees of freezing begins to form momentary crystal structures. The crystal structure of water is exceptionally spread out, so the solid is less dense than the liquid. Ice is one of the few solids that floats in its liquid.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, it's really useful, actually I am trying to make a very simplified numerical model of thermal expansion. I started using Lennard-Jones potential because in Sears & Zemansky (Fig. 17.9, page 557, I assume I am not allowed to upload the figure here) they use a potential that looks a lot like that.

To be honest, I don't care if it's a metal or not, but if I were to study thermal expansion experimentally, I would use a metal.

Answer (score 0):

> I guess that the first question is, can a Lennard-Jones potential be
> used to (roughly) study distance between atoms in a metal?

This is a really subtle question. You can either do a trivial but non realistic thing, or a more difficult and more realistic thing.

**The simple one**: you assume that the interaction between non nearest neighbours sites is negligible. In this case the total energy is minimized when the distance between two nearest neighbours is the minimum of the potential.

**The difficult one**: you don't assume anything, so your lattice minimizes the total energy per particle, which is
$$
\mathcal{E}(a) = \frac{1}{2} \sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty} V(r_n) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} V(na),
$$
where the factor $1/2$ avoids double counting of interactions, $r_n = n a$ with $n=\pm 1, \pm 2, ...$ is the distance between the origin site and another site, and $V$ is the Lennard-Jones potential. You get
$$
\mathcal{E}(a) = 4 \varepsilon \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left[ \left( \frac{\sigma}{na} \right)^{12} - \left( \frac{\sigma}{na} \right)^6 \right],
$$
where $\varepsilon$ and $\sigma$ are the parameters of LJ potential.
You can minimize this function with respect to $a$ and use computational tools to evaluate the sums, and you should get your equilibrium lattice parameter $a$.

> But which charge would I use to calculate the force?

I don't think you need any charge, you just need to consider the gradient of the potential. For instance let's consider the force between nearest neighbours, if $a$ is the equilibrium distance you have found in the previous part. You should do
$$
F = - \left. \frac{\partial V(r)}{\partial r} \right|_{r=a}.
$$
For second neighbours you just evaluate the derivative at $2a$ and so on.
If you use the simple way to evaluate $a$ this result would be trivially 0.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed reply. However, I don't understand the last formula, maybe it's the weekend brain. If I calculate the gradient of the potential, wouldn't I get the field? And for the force, I would need the gradient of the potential energy. In that equation, the units don't add up.

Comment: Wait, is Lennard-Jones potential actually Lennard-Jones potential energy?
If so, I had completely forgotten about that since I studied it.