# A certain potential shape reoccuring in physics

Tags: potential

[image: reoccurring shape]

I have seen this shape  in many different phenomena in physics, for example- when two neutral atoms are brought together, then potential between them as a function of separation takes this type of shape, also in kepplers law I have seen this type of potential. Today I was studying QM, and I saw this shape of potential again $$V= \frac{l(l+1)}{2mr^2} + \frac{-e^2}{r}$$ Where $\dfrac{-e^2}{r}$ is coulomb potential.

What is so special about this type of shape of potential, that it occurs in many different phenomena?

Comment: For me a Lennard Jones potential is something like $V=\frac{a}{r^6} + \frac{b}{r^{12}}$. I strongly doubt that your potential is a LJ potential. Please check!

Comment: The form you give for $V$ is not Lennard-Jones (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lennard-Jones_potential) which is usually in $r^{-6}$ and $r^{-12}$.  Your shaped just has the centrifugal part added, as in any radial motion in a $3D$ problem.

Comment: My answer here explains a bit about the Lennard-Jones potential and more general potentials. https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/557733/37364

Comment: I think the only thing in common between the two potentials you listed is that they both get big at small $r$, go to zero at large $r$, and have a dip in the middle. The second thing is basically automatic, the other two are fairly common.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general shape of the potential you've displayed describes any system that has a **single stable bound state** with a **finite binding energy**.

The fact that the potential has a minimum at finite $r$ gives it a stable bound state. The fact that it has only one extremum (i.e. minimum or maximum) means that it only has a single bound state. And the fact that the potential asymptotically approaches a finite value at large $r$ means that the system can be separated using a finite amount of energy (and therefore has a finite binding energy).

This potential is common because many bound systems in nature can be approximated, under certain conditions, as having a single stable bound state with a finite binding energy. The bound systems that we know how to study well have two general properties:

- They last long enough for us to measure, and
- We can take them apart and put them together.

The first property requires the existence of at least one stable bound state, and the second property requires a finite binding energy. Systems that violate one of these two principles are much harder to understand. Transitional states in chemical reactions violate the first property, and as such their structure is hard to determine; the proton, as a bound state of quarks, violates the second property, and so our understanding of the strong force is very limited.